# Rails activerecord .select causing object to have all nil attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I'm using Rails 3.2.13, Ruby 2.0.0p-p247, and Spree 2.0.3.

Using activerecord in rails console, or in my actual app, if I run: `Spree::Product.select(:permalink).first` I get `#<Spree::Product permalink: nil>`

However, if I run `Spree::Product.first.permalink` I get `"test"`, the expected permalink. Additionally, `Spree::Product.first` returns the whole activerecord relation for the product.

I try running `Spree::Product.create(name: "test", price: "100")` in `RAILS_ENV=development rails c` and it works as expected. If I try in `RAILS_ENV=test rails c`, I get a SQL rollback, and a `NoMethodError: undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass`.

Any idea why this is happening only in test env?

Comment: Is your test database up to date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a bug with `spreei18n` gem, which I submitted a pull request for.

https://github.com/spree/spree/commit/09b55f7be8720f0d6d16822f4ce23c961d1c66f5